# busybox dmesg old timestamp format

Tags: linux, busybox, dmesg

I'm working on an arm board running an old kernel(3.14.29)

I trying to to get the `dmesg` output and pass it to the [bootgraph.pl](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/bootgraph.pl) to generate an SVG of kernel boot sequence.
However after passing the `dmesg` output to `bootgraph.pl` I get:

```
Illegal division by zero at bootgraph.pl line 179
```

After some digging, I found out that the timestamp of the `busybox dmesg` output is not standard.

So for example in the standard `dmesg` provided by util-linux the output is this:

```
[    0.037644] calling  trace_init_flags_sys_exit+0x0/0x14 @ 1
[    0.037650] initcall trace_init_flags_sys_exit+0x0/0x14 returned 0 after 0 usecs
[    0.037656] calling  trace_init_flags_sys_enter+0x0/0x14 @ 1
[    0.037661] initcall trace_init_flags_sys_enter+0x0/0x14 returned 0 after 0 usecs
[    0.037666] calling  init_hw_perf_events+0x0/0x150 @ 1
[    0.037670] hw perfevents: enabled with arm/armv8-pmuv3 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    0.037697] initcall init_hw_perf_events+0x0/0x150 returned 0 after 0 usecs
[    0.037701] calling  cpu_suspend_init+0x0/0xa4 @ 1
[    0.037707] initcall cpu_suspend_init+0x0/0xa4 returned 0 after 0 usecs
[    0.037713] calling  spawn_ksoftirqd+0x0/0x64 @ 1
[    0.057161] initcall spawn_ksoftirqd+0x0/0x64 returned 0 after 19531 usecs
```

while the output of the `busybox dmesg` looks like the following:

```
[    0.037644@0] calling  trace_init_flags_sys_exit+0x0/0x14 @ 1
[    0.037650@0] initcall trace_init_flags_sys_exit+0x0/0x14 returned 0 after 0 usecs
[    0.037656@0] calling  trace_init_flags_sys_enter+0x0/0x14 @ 1
[    0.037661@0] initcall trace_init_flags_sys_enter+0x0/0x14 returned 0 after 0 usecs
[    0.037666@0] calling  init_hw_perf_events+0x0/0x150 @ 1
[    0.037670@0] hw perfevents: enabled with arm/armv8-pmuv3 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    0.037697@0] initcall init_hw_perf_events+0x0/0x150 returned 0 after 0 usecs
[    0.037701@0] calling  cpu_suspend_init+0x0/0xa4 @ 1
[    0.037707@0] initcall cpu_suspend_init+0x0/0xa4 returned 0 after 0 usecs
[    0.037713@0] calling  spawn_ksoftirqd+0x0/0x64 @ 1
[    0.057161@0] initcall spawn_ksoftirqd+0x0/0x64 returned 0 after 19531 usecs
```

The problem in the second output is the @ sign and the number after it [    0.037661`@0`] , after removing all the occurrences of this substring `bootgraph.pl` was able to parse the log and generate the SVG.

So my question is what does this string (@0) refer to and can I remove it from busybox dmesg output?

**EDIT:** note that looking at the serial console as the board boots, I see the same messages as the `busybox dmesg` (the second format with the `@digit`), So I think the problem related to the old kernel having a different format, So was there any changes regarding this in the kernel after version 3.14.29? or is this added to the kernel by the board vender?

Comment: I don't see off-hand where [busybox's dmesg](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/util-linux/dmesg.c) is adding a `@0`; do you get the same output with `dmesg -r` (for raw mode)? I suspect all that may do is print leading `<(digits)>`

Comment: Well, running `busybox dmesg` produces the same format with the added log level
`<6>[    6.912810@3] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast`
I don't think the problem is in the `busybox dmesg` instead it's in the kernel (3.14.29) because even when the kernel boot's I can see in the serial console the same format, for some reason the `busybox dmesg` print the messages as they are and the util-linux `dmesg strips the `@digit` part

Comment: indeed, the [parse_syslog_timestamp](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/dmesg.c#L447) function uses strtol (which stops at the @), and then returns a pointer that's skipped over the timestamp (after saving it).

Comment: @JeffSchaller Great, So what does `@digit` signify?